# Es posible que el metodo de moment format, no funcione bien?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs, formato

Me enquentro con lo siguiente, tengo que darle formato a unas fechas y siempre había utilizado el moments. Ahora tengo este dilema:

```
var date2 = new Date(year, 6, 0);
var dateEnd = formatShortDate(date2.toString());
```

y el metodo `formatShortDate`, que es el siguiente:

```
export function formatShortDate(date: string, originalFormat: string = "", finalFormat: string = "DD/MM/YYYY"): string {
 var possibleInputFormats = [
    'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss',
    'DD/MM/YYYY',
    'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.mmm',
    'MMMM Do YYYY, H:m:s a',
    'x',
    'DDMMYYYY',
    'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss',
]

if (date) {
    var momentObj = moment(date, possibleInputFormats);
    if (!momentObj.isValid()) {
        momentObj = getMomentValid(date);
    }
    return momentObj.format(finalFormat);
}
else {
    return '';
}
```

Este siempre devuelve el dia 30/1/2017, ¿por qué podría ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el método [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) del objeto `Date` *retorna la fecha en un formato no incluido en tu arreglo `possibleInputFormats`*.

Ejemplo:

```
new Date(2017, 6, 0).toString();
// "Fri Jun 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Local Standard Time)"
```

Una solución sería:

- Utilizar el metodo [`.toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) del objeto `Date`.
- Agregar el formato `ISO` al arreglo `possibleInputFormats`.

Ejemplo:

```js
var possibleInputFormats = [
  'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss',
  'DD/MM/YYYY',
  'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.mmm',
  'MMMM Do YYYY, H:m:s a',
  'x',
  'DDMMYYYY',
  'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss',
  moment.ISO_8601 // Agregamos el formato ISO
];
var date = new Date(2017, 6, 0); // 30/06/2017

// Utilizamos el metodo "toISOString()"
console.log(moment(date.toISOString(), possibleInputFormats).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasó fue que pusiste día 0:

```
var date2 = new Date(year, 6, 0);
```

Los días comienzan en 1, los meses en 0 los años en 1. Se debe hacer así:

```
var date2 = new Date(year, month-1, day);
```

Comment: el zero es porque coja el ultimo dia del mes que quiero, Gracias por responder!!